# A problem involving the volume between the surface of a cylinder and a sphere around it

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, volume, surfaces

The core (a cylinder with radius $r = 1$) is taken out of a sphere with radius $r = 4 $

Part 1: Write equations for the spherical surface + the cylindrical surface of the cylinder in rectangular coordinates, assuming they are centered on the origin.

**Attempt.** My answer so far: I assume these are just the standard equations for spherical surface:
$$(x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2 + (z - c)^2 = r^2$$
and a right circular cylinder:
$$x^2+y^2=a^2$$

Part 2: Draw each of the surfaces from part (a),
separately; make sure to label reference points for scale (i.e. intercepts w/ axes).

**Attempt.** I know I can use traces to sketch this

Part 3: Find where the two surfaces intersect; express these intersection curves in terms of chosen coordinates.

**Attempt.** This part is puzzling me

Part 4: Find the volume outside of the cylinder and inside the sphere as a set of inequalities using the same coordinate system you used in part (c).

**Attempt.** This part is even more puzzling, not sure how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Center your cylinder and sphere at the origin.

$x^2+y^2=1\\
x^2+y^2+z^2 = 4^2$

The intersection is a circle.

Subtract one equation from the other.

$z^2 = 15\\
z = \pm \sqrt {15}$

$x^2+y^2 = 1,$ and $z= \pm \sqrt {15}$

$V = \frac 43 \pi (\sqrt {15})^3$